Is there a Shorthand/notation for "R is a relation form A to B"?
The question is essentially what the title says; is there a shorthand/notation for "$R$ is a relation form $A$ to $B$" or the general version "$R$ is a relation between $A_1$, ..., $A_n$" or do we always use natural language?
For the set-wise definition of relations, we write $R \subseteq A_1 \times ... \times A_n$ or even use set-builder notation, but this is not sufficient as the reflexive property uses the full domains rather than some narrow domains. For example, I could say that a relation is defined by $R \subseteq A \times B$ without $A$ and $B$ being the domains of R; or do we always assert that the sets used in the subset as the domains?
Or does it in the cases where these specifics are necessary, make more sense to define the relation as a tuple or some other object that includes the domains?
